# Sublocation for Trac on Apache2 web server

Tags: apache2, trac

I need to put Trac on a URL path other than /. If I take the configuration from http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnUbuntu and modify the Location blocks, I get the error message "No handler matched request to /trac". How can I avoid this?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName trac.local
    <Location /trac> # instead of Location /
       SetHandler mod_python
       PythonInterpreter main_interpreter
       PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
       PythonOption TracEnv /var/local/trac
       PythonOption TracEnvParentDir /var/local/trac
       PythonOption TracUriRoot /
       PythonOption TracEnv /var/local/trac
        # PythonOption TracEnvIndexTemplate /var/local/trac/templates/index-template.html
       PythonOption TracLocale en_US.UTF8
       PythonOption PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /tmp
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Location>
    <Location /trac/login> # instead of /login
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "myproject"
      AuthUserFile /var/local/trac/.htpasswd
      Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adjusting 'PythonOption TracUriRoot /' too?

Furthermore please acknowledge, that mod_python is depreciated (end-of-life), and you should rather [choose WSGI](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracModWSGI) for new installations instead.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think of this option. Now it works. @deprecated: I just did a brand-new Trac setup and followed the instructions on the TracOnUbuntu wiki (http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnUbuntu). It nowhere states this is not the recommended way of setting up Trac together with Apache.

Comment: Sure, just the age of most of its content is speaking against taking that wiki page too serious.

Comment: 10 months is not really old.